# Reach max with input type range and step

Tags: html, input, range

Please consider this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/orfm0ae5/

```
<input type="range" step="100" max="2191">
```

The defined step prevent the user to reach the max set to 2191 (can only reach 2100). Is there a workaround solution?

Comment: Can you increase `max` to `2200`?

Comment: its not possible with step 100

Comment: why downvoting the question?

Comment: @JonnyHenly nope. The thing is this value is calculated and dynamic. The user should still be able to reach the max but with step 100 he can't...

Comment: @Don'tBenegative don't be so negative ;)

Comment: Wait is `max` calculated or is `step`? If `max` is calculated and you want `step` to be less equal to 100 then you could calculate the greatest multiple of `max` that is less equal to 100. Then you could have the largest `step` that also hits `max`. This approach would fail for primes greater than 100 though.

Comment: I thought about something like this but as you mentionned, it doesn't always work and it's somehow weird to have a different value for step (for UX). Too bad that input range doesn't let you reach the max :/

Comment: I am not Downvoted... I am not voted yat...Remember I will always Upvote ... once ask @Jonny Henly He downvoted my answer also...

Comment: I voted the question back up to zero, it's a good question

Answer (score 0):

I just play something like that! :D

[codepen](https://codepen.io/giacomo1203/pen/MWQebww)

```
let sValue;
let isMouseDown = false;
let step = 10;
let restStep = 5;
let maxStep = 50;
let prevMaxStep = 40;
let prevErrorStep = 45;

const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
const label = document.getElementById('label');

function onChange() {
  sValue = Number(slider.value);

  if (sValue == maxStep || sValue == prevErrorStep) {
    slider.step = restStep;
  } else {
    if (sValue < maxStep) {
        slider.step = step;
    
        if (sValue > prevMaxStep) slider.value = maxStep;
      }
  };

  if (sValue < maxStep && sValue > prevMaxStep) {
    slider.step = restStep;
    slider.value = maxStep;
  }

  label.innerText = slider.value;
}

function sayValue() {
  console.log({
    value: slider.value,
    step: slider.step
  });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

use this

```
<input type="range" step="1" max="2191">
```

so that you can reach "2191"

you see this...

[image]

Comment: Set `step` to 1 in the linked jsfiddle and see if you can land on any hundred value.

Comment: Can you do it with your mouse only? I'll remove my down-vote if OP says this was helpful. Otherwise it's just pointing out the obvious and seems contradictory to OP's intentions.

Comment: The idea is to keep the step constraint :)